# DRF - How do I whitelist a site for endpoint requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my scenario:

- Hosted Django application running DRF
- External site hosted elsewhere. Could be multiple sites.

My question is: How do I whitelist any Javascript POST request from an external site? For example I want to add a Javascript post request on a forms confirmation page. How do I do this so my DRF application only accepts requests from this site only? I'm trying not to use server site code. Just Javascript so it easily applied.

My concern is anyone that views the source will be able to view the API endpoint and would be able to submit POST requests.

Comment: Which web server are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Nginx

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a whitelist by creating a custom permissions class, here is an example from the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class BlacklistPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for blacklisted IPs.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        blacklisted = Blacklist.objects.filter(ip_addr=ip_addr).exists()
        return not blacklisted
```

For a whitelist implementation you would want to grab the `REMOTE_HOST` from the incoming request and compare it against a predefined list of urls, which could be stored in the database or in a list in the class. it might look something list this:

```
# Model

class Whitelist(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField()

# Permission
class WhitelistPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for whitelisted IPs.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        domain = request.META['REMOTE_HOST']
        whitelisted = Whitelist.objects.filter(host=domain).exists()
        return whitelisted
```

Or you could whitelist based off IP be replacing `REMOTE_HOST` with `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: Could an attacker not spoof the domain name? Then access the API? If so how would I secure this? So only requests from a certain domain or server are allowed? Can't be server side. Request needs to come from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can configure this in your web server. So that request is blocked at the entry level itself.

If you're using nginx then something like this https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/blocking-allowing-ip-addresses-in-nginx/